# VSCT: Different icons for different VS versions

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsct

I am making an extension for both VS2010 and VS2012 that has a toolbar command.
Given the change in icon style between them, I want to provide a separate icon for each.

How do I specify that in `.vsct`? I assume I might be able to use `Condition`, but I am not sure if there is already a pre-defined value with VS version.

Comment: It seems it is not easily possible? See "[VS2011 vspackage command button icons](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/9bd1810b-f5c0-42dd-8a38-4ed1046a41b6)" on MSDN forums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems it is not possible without using an MSI, see "[VS Package (VSIX): Having two different toolbar icons for VS2010/VS2012](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/b44cd3a9-933d-43e9-ba59-0cfe3e3f2adb)" on MSDN forums.

> [Ryan Molden (MSFT)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/ryan%20molden):
>
> I do not believe you can use VSIX to install or specify target specific resources. VSIX is intended as a very simplistic deployment mechanism, it is in fact just a renamed ZIP file plus an installer with a small amount of logic to process pkgdef files. If you want more complex installs (like laying down different dlls based on your install target) I believe you would need to create an MSI.